# XPath error - Trying to get user by name from the database

Tags: database, list, listview, xpath, mendix

I'm working on a list of tasks. Users can request to be assigned to a task, and Admin can approve or reject this request.

I almost have it done, but have a **problem with the XPath statement in the last 3rd step**.

---

Implementation step-by-step:

1. I created the tasks entity and associated it with the Administration.Account entity, this way I can assign users to tasks using reference selector.

[image]

2. In each list item, there is a "request assignment" button, when User clicks on it, a microflow takes the name of the current user and saves it to the "requester" string parameter of this item.
3. When Admin approves a request, a microflow should find the user with the same username as the one stored in the requestor parameter, and associate this list item with this user.

I have a problem with the last 3rd step. As you can see on the screenshot below, I created a microflow and I use Retrieve action to get the user from the database of all registered users. I use this XPath expression, which should help me get only one user, whose name is the same as the name stored in the "requestor" string parameter of the tasks entity:

```
[Name = $Tasks.Requester]
```

But I'm getting an error, and don't understand how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: The image in your first step shows the element name as `requestor` while your xpath uses `Requester`. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @JackFleeting Thank you, I changed it, but the error remains. Another strange thing, I don't understand why after typing "$Tasks." and see available parameters, all the parameters belong to the Administration.Account entity, not to the Tasks entity.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rumata, the right way to access the parameter's/object's attributes is using '/' symbol instead of '.' symbol. When you type / as shown below you will be shown all the attributes if 'Tasks' instead of Administration.Account entity.

[Name = $Tasks/Requester]

The '.' symbol is used only when trying to access an enumeration's value in a if statement or exclusive split.

Example:  variable1 = module.enumname.value